# Xpath up to parent element using nightwatch

Tags: css, xpath, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have this structure:

```
 <div class="class">
    <h4 class="class2"> 
      "Condition" </h4>
    <div class = "click_class">Click_text  </div>
 </div>
```

I heed to click on the element with `class ="click_class"` if the `h4` `text == "Condition"`.

I try `Xpath`:

```
 .useXpath()
 .click('//div[contains(@class, "class")]//h4[text()[contains(.,"Condition")]
```

It is works. I found the h4 with `text` == `"Condition"`. Now, in my opinion, I need to go to parent `class` and click on `click_class`.

```
.click('//div[contains(@class, "class")]//h4[text()[contains(.,"Condition")]..//div[text()="Click_text"]')
```

but it is not works.

How can I click on the element with text with condition in `h4`?

Answer (score 1):

Try below `XPath`:

```
//h4[normalize-space(text())="Condition"]/following-sibling::div[@class="click_class"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can put the expression that *check for text content of `h4`* in a predicate for the parent `div` instead :

```
//div[contains(@class, "class")][h4/text()[contains(.,"Condition")]]
```

and then navigate to return child `div` element that have class "click_class" :

```
/div[contains(@class, "click_class")]
```

So the entire expression would be as follows (wrapped for readability) :

```
//div[contains(@class, "class")][h4/text()[contains(.,"Condition")]]
/div[contains(@class, "click_class")]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/z01cI8KfJ)</kbd>**